# Want to go back to my original Ubuntu look

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, 15.04

How can I go to my original Ubuntu 14.04 look?  Now I have a display that have the activities bar at the top,the dock hidden at the left . It's not the original look. Ho can I have my original 14.04 look?

Comment: You have Ubuntu in the title, but you have xubuntu in the tags. As I understand you have modified xfce environment, right ? now Ubuntu's default unity desktop ?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Very good. Now what about activities bar ? is that an external application you've installed ?

Comment: I've posted a small answer, but i still need to figure out what are you reffering to with the activities bar

Answer (score 0):

Default Unity theme is Ambiance, which can be reset through Settings -> Appearance, or with the command

`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme "'Ambiance'"`

Unity Launcher can be unhidden with

`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 0`